# Android issue of classnotfound exception below android 5 and working fine above 6+

Tags: crash, build.gradle, android-5.0-lollipop, android-multidex

Can any one help me out on this my app is multidex enabled and I am having issue on the android version 5 and below 5 my app is crashing due to the classnot found exception infact the class is present still.`

My Gradle file is -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.brightcove.com/releases'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.weone.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 31
        versionName "1.2.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/WeOneWithExoPlayer/weone-android/certificate/WeOne.jks')
            storePassword 'WeOneKey'
            keyAlias 'weone'
            keyPassword 'WeOneKey'
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('/home/user/.android/debug.keystore')
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
       //     signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          //  signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           // multiDexKeepFile file 'multidex-config.txt'
        }

    }
   /* afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = []
            }
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex' // enable multidex

            // optional
            // dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/<filename>".toString() // enable the main-dex-list
        }
    }*/
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.+'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.naver.android.helloyako:imagecropview:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'com.brightcove.player:exoplayer:4.+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.turbomanage.basic-http-client:http-client-android:0.89'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev182-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.+'
    compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.+'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.+'
}
```

And Project Gradle is -

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }

}

allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()

            maven {
                url 'http://lorenzo.villani.me/android-cropimage/'
            }
        }
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://jitpack.io"
            }
            maven {
                url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
            }
        }
    }
```

My app is crashng below 5 and I am stuck in it from last 2 weeks.
Haven't got solution till now. :(

stacktrace ---------------------------------------------------

```
04-06 16:10:33.314 21020-21020/com.weone.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.weone.android, PID: 21020
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/api/client/extensions/android/http/AndroidHttp;
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.constants.Config.<clinit>(Config.java:26)
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.constants.Config.setAppModeConfig(Config.java:0)
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.apporganizer.ApplicationProperties.initThings(ApplicationProperties.java:59)
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.apporganizer.ApplicationProperties.access$000(ApplicationProperties.java:29)
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.apporganizer.ApplicationProperties$1.run(ApplicationProperties.java:44)
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.apporganizer.ApplicationProperties.onCreate(ApplicationProperties.java:51)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1035)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4638)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.weone.android-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.constants.Config.<clinit>(Config.java:26) 
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.constants.Config.setAppModeConfig(Config.java:0) 
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.apporganizer.ApplicationProperties.initThings(ApplicationProperties.java:59) 
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.apporganizer.ApplicationProperties.access$000(ApplicationProperties.java:29) 
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.apporganizer.ApplicationProperties$1.run(ApplicationProperties.java:44) 
       at com.weone.android.utilities.helpers.apporganizer.ApplicationProperties.onCreate(ApplicationProperties.java:51) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1035) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4638) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 18 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: done.And i have class Android Client present with the library i have added and also working with 6+

Comment: You're instantiating an `com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp` instance from `Application#onCreate` using reflection. I believe that this class is not being included in primary dex file, classes.dex (the reason for that is listed [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep)). Can you verify that (using Android Studio's Apk Analyzer)?

Comment: any solution? Having the same issue

Comment: yeah just replace the bundled google play services with the individual library.and also if you are using any library you thing is included in some libraries internally so just exclude them...it will solve your problem.